# Visual brush weird behavior

Tags: wpf

I have a textbox and a rectangle. The rectangle updates itself when textbox content changes. I'm painting the rectangle fill with visual brush. The problem is that the visual brush don't match the textbox's actual look. What should I do. Here's my code:

```
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <TextBox Name="txtBox"/>

        <Rectangle Height="{Binding ElementName=txtBox, Path=ActualHeight}"
                   Width="{Binding ElementName=txtBox, Path=ActualWidth}">
            <Rectangle.Fill>
               <VisualBrush Visual="{Binding ElementName=txtBox}"/>
            <Rectangle.Fill>
            <Rectangle.LayoutTransform>
                <ScaleTransform ScaleY="-0.75"/>
            </Rectangle.LayoutTransform>
        </Rectangle>
    </StackPanel>
```

Here I wrote "Visual Brush",

[image]
then deleted few chars and look what I got:
[image]

Comment: You should provide some more info like what exactly are you getting (showing and image would be the best).

Comment: Just dropping your code in an empty window doesn't reproduce your problem as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Meleak I think it's the problem with changing textbox content at runtime, try changing it

Comment: Oh I did, made i very long, very short, changed the `ScaleTransform` with a `Slider`. I have seen this problem with `VisualBrush` before though, just unable to reproduce it with the code above. Anything special I should try?

Comment: @Meleak I have a textblock and I'm changing it's text with a textbox. Try to add a textbox and on it's textChnaged event change the textblock's text.

Comment: @Cobold: Ok, that did it. Try to set the `Background` of the `TextBlock` to `Transparent` (instead of null which is the default value)

Comment: @Meleak This worked. But why isn't the textblock always in the center of view? When I delete chars, the stackpanel doesn't sets it's horizontal alignment to center.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3541/discussion-between-meleak-and-cobold)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Made a small change to your Xaml based on the information in your comment. The problem seems to be that the `TextBlock` doesn't have a `Background` so I guess that the `VisualBrush` just finds the visible part of the `TextBlock` for rendering and then stretches it to the full length of the `TextBlock` based on the Bindings.

The following Xaml works fine when the `TextBlock` has `Background="Transparent"` but reproduces your problem without it

**Update:**  In the chat, the OP found that the `Width` Binding kept the `TextBox` from shrinking when deleting characters. So removing the `Width` binding fixes the centering issue as well.

```
<StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <TextBox Name="txtBox"/>
    <TextBlock Name="textBlock" Text="{Binding ElementName=txtBox, Path=Text}"
               Background="Transparent"/>
    <Rectangle Height="{Binding ElementName=textBlock, Path=ActualHeight}">
        <Rectangle.Fill>
            <VisualBrush Visual="{Binding ElementName=textBlock}"/>
        </Rectangle.Fill>
        <Rectangle.LayoutTransform>
            <ScaleTransform ScaleY="5"/>
        </Rectangle.LayoutTransform>
    </Rectangle>
</StackPanel>
```